# Amazon alexa with ROS running locally

Tags: ros, rosbridge, roslibjs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running alexa-app server locally on my robot using roslibjs on port 8081, a websocket server (rosbridge_server) on port 9090 and i have connected the alexa-server to a ros service running on the robot to send commands to it.( For example: Move from point A to B).

I have tried using bespoke tunnel however, it did not work well. Right now I'm trying to use ngrok to forward the alexa server running on 8081 so that my alexa skills kit can then communicate with it.

When i test my skill on alexa skills kit the request is sent correctly however, when i test using voice commands using an echo im getting an error.

Is there any other way to connect the alexa skills kit (running remotely) with the alexa-app server (running locally) ?

Here's the link of the github repo i am using for this: https://github.com/mdeyo/alexa-node-ROS

My goal is to use amazon echo to control the robot (running on ROS) using voice commands.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267145/amazon-alexa-with-ros-running-locally/) by [c9zealous](https://answers.ros.org/users/31313/c9zealous/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-07-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mumie](https://answers.ros.org/users/31881/mumie/) on 2018-01-22**:
Hello,

I might ask if you found a solution to your problem? Did the ngrok solution work out?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you ultimately want is to pass ROS-formatted commands to your ROS node I suppose. So at minimum you have 3 modules of pipeline like the following:

```
(A) Sensor(s) -- (B) Message conversion -- (C) ROS
```

In your case,

> Is there any other way to connect the alexa skills kit (running remotely) with the alexa-app server (running locally) ?

I'm not entire sure but this sounds like your issue is happening in (A). In that case I don't think this forum is the best place for your question (this forum is for (B) and (C)).

Btw, looking at [the link you shared](https://github.com/mdeyo/alexa-node-ROS) conversaion layer seems to already exist, but I just want to raise an attention for [wiki.ros.org/iot_bridge](http://wiki.ros.org/iot_bridge) that connects ROS and `openHAB` where there's already [binding for Alexa skills](https://community.openhab.org/t/official-alexa-smart-home-skill-for-openhab-2/23533).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0